# Access 2010 why am I being prompted to enter parameter value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Here is my sub-query from Access 2010. I'm prompting user to input year (yyyy) and Month (1-12) but for some reason user is also getting prompted for Site. Can someone tell me why? I do not want user prompted for Site.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Year (yyyy)] Text ( 255 ), [Enter Month (1-12)] Short;
SELECT Sum([AB Units]) AS [Monthly AB Units], 
SELECT Count(*) FROM [New  Referrals] 
   WHERE ((Year([New Referrals].[Date of Referral]) = [Enter Year (yyyy)]) 
   AND (Month([New Referrals].[Date of Referral]) = [Enter Month (1-12)]))
   AND ([New Referrals].[First Visit] Is Null) 
   AND (([New Referrals].Site)="2")) 
 AS Waitlist FROM [DNS] 
WHERE (((Year([DNS].[Date of Entry]))=[Enter Year (yyyy)]) 
   AND ((Month([DNS].[Date of Entry]))=[Enter Month (1-12)]) 
   AND (([DNS].Site)="2"));
```

Joe

Comment: Cannot post my query code for some reason. Keep getting message - An error occurred during comment submission.

Comment: You reference `[DNS].Site` and `[New Referrals].Site` Is that exactly the name of the column in DNS? Id you misspell a column (i.e. a column in a query cannot be found in a referenced table) it is treated as a parameter instead.

Comment: Also this query cannot work as is. I assume you're missing a `(` after `[Monthly AB Units],`

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that the field called Site is not in either [New Referrals] or [DNS].  Check both tables and make sure that field exists in them, since there is a reference to that field in your query.

For further review, take a look at [this article on the Microsoft website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Why-does-Access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-a7344543-e758-4785-8433-420eb0f0b48e).

Answer (score 0):

Like @JohnnyBones suggests it's most likely a misnamed field, but saying that you do have a syntax error that should show up in your SQL View:

You're missing a bracket that goes with the first WHERE clause

This

```
WHERE ((Year([New Referrals].[Date of Referral])
```

should be this:

```
WHERE (((Year([New Referrals].[Date of Referral])
```

A good text editor (I use Textpad) will show you matching brackets - and more importantly which ones don't have a match